# Cross page posting asp.net vs asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a doubt on cross page posting in asp.net.

1.)Why are we asked to use `PreviousPage` class/API but not Request.Form collection in target page? I mean, Why can't we read the values from previous page into target page using Request.Form collection.

2.)Why isn't such cross page posting is exist in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 1):

1. When you are using transfer method from one asp.net page to another, the originating page contains request information and so you will need to use PreviousPage.
2. I am not sure what you are trying to do, but similar thing  can be achieved by posting to a different controller action method in mvc.